# python - for loop in range continues populating data instead of exiting the loop

Tags: python

In the following code,

```
no_of_sheet_b = 6
row_count_b = 39
```

I would expect that when j = 7 (i.e. for the final "Sheet 7), the data from rows 37, 38, 39 of dataframe "df_s" will be copied to columns 10, 14, 18, respectively, of worksheet_for_b.cell (which will be saved as "Sheet 7" in this last iteration), and the columns 22, 26, and 30 would be empty (this is what I want). But loop i is completing the iteration even if row_index > row_count_b, and populating columns 22, 26, 30 of "Sheet 7" with data from cols 22, 26, 30 from the previous sheet ("Sheet 6"). How can I make i loop completely stop populating columns when row_index > row_count_b?

```
row_index = 0
location_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 1"]
sample_no_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 2"]
top_depth_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 3"]
   

# Iterate over the rows of df_s
for j in range(1, no_of_sheet_b + 1, 1):
    for i in range(10, 31, 4):
        # Check if row_index is within the valid range
        if row_index < row_count_b:
            # Copy the data to the appropriate cells in worksheet_for_b
            worksheet_for_b.cell(row=9, column=i).value = location_value
            worksheet_for_b.cell(row=12, column=i).value = sample_no_value
            worksheet_for_b.cell(row=15, column=i).value = top_depth_value

            worksheet_for_b.cell(row=7, column=4, value=f'{date_assigned}')
            worksheet_for_b.cell(row=7, column=12, value=f'{project_name}')
            worksheet_for_b.cell(row=7, column=24, value=f'{job_no}')

            # jump to next row
            row_index += 1
            if row_index < row_count_b:
                location_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 1"]
                sample_no_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 2"]
                top_depth_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 3"]
       workbook_for_b.save(f"results_folder\\Sheet {j}.xlsx")
```

Comment: _I would expect that when j = 7_ In that loop, j will **never** be 7.  `range()` loops stop **before** they reach the end limit.  So your expectation makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple approach you can add a condition to break out of the loop when `row_index >= row_count_b`. That is you can edit the following couple lines in your code:

```
            # jump to next row
            row_index += 1
            if row_index < row_count_b:
                location_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 1"]
                sample_no_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 2"]
                top_depth_value = df_s.at[row_index, "Column 3"]
       else:
            break

       workbook_for_b.save(f"results_folder\\Sheet {j}.xlsx")
```